# Why is my confusion_matrix not displayed correctly?

Tags: scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have been experimenting with the iris dataset and wanted to create a confusion matrix. My code to create the confusion matrix is this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

mat = confusion_matrix(ytest, y_model)

sns.heatmap(mat, square=True, annot=True, cbar=False)
plt.xlabel('predicted value')
plt.ylabel('true value');
```

The result is somehow cut off at the top and the bottom. I need help to figure out why...can you help?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/57245/seaborn-heatmap-not-displaying-correctly

Comment: Also, you can use `plot_confusion_matrix` in scikit-learn 0.22 which will manage the heatmap for you as well.

Comment: It's the problem with matplotlib version. Downgrade it

Comment: @glemaitre thanks, but how would I implement your solution in my code? The module plot_confusion_matrix does not seem to be in my sklearn.metrics module....I get an error message: cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics'. Could you make an example, please?

Comment: Available in scikit-learn 0.22 -> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html

Comment: @glemaitre I am lost...I have checked the documentation and your link but don't know, how to implement this function plot_confusion_matrix. It has much more parameters than confusion_matrix.

Comment: You need to provide the fitted classifier, the training data, and the corresponding labels

Comment: @glemaitre ok thanks, I‘ll try it out.